# How to use filter for more than one parameter in wso2 ESB

Tags: xpath, service, filter, wso2

I know to check for a parameter, we have to do something like this

use boolean xpath function to verify if your property exist :

```
<filter xpath="boolean(get-property('ModifiedOn'))">
   <then> 
      ...
   </then>
   <else>
      ...
   </else>
</filter>
```

can you please tell me how can i check if more than one parameter is there. I mean we need to check 3 parameters. how can we do this ?

Comment: Please do not add code in comments. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks for code formatting.

Answer (score 3):

Specify all of your criteria that must be true and evaluate as a boolean:

```
<filter xpath="boolean(boolean(get-property('ModifiedOn') and 
                       boolean(get-property('prop2')) and 
                       boolean(get-property('prop3'))">
   <then> 
      ...
   </then>
   <else>
      ...
   </else>
</filter>
```

Comment: You save my time.Thanks mads

Comment: This is giving me invalid path expression, can it be not supported by my wso2 version?

Answer (score 0):

As a solution you can set the parameters as below:

```
<filter xpath="fn:number(get-property('SIMPLE_SER_AMT')) > fn:number(get-property('SECURE_SER_AMT'))">
```

For more information you can refer Sample 156: Service Integration with specifying the receiving sequence available on [[1]](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB451/Sample+156%3A+Service+Integration+with+specifying+the+receiving+sequence)

Hope this information will help you.

Answer (score 0):

For my case none of the listed solutions worked. I am using WSO2 version: 6.5
I was able to make multiple conditions as follows:

```
<filter regex="true" source="boolean(get-property('VALUE1')) and boolean(get-property('VALUE2')) and boolean(get-property('VALUE3'))">
<then> ...
```

This expression will make sure that value 1 and 2 and 3 are filled before running the code in the 'then' clause.